# How do you have Excel VBA run a task based on the information inside selected cells?

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following VBA code that runs on user input. I want to speed up this task by having the code run based on what is selected instead of what is typed in. I found some other explanations on how to do this, but when I applied them to my code, it didn't run.

```
Sub Fill_and_Print_Empty_Curing()
    Dim jobNumber As String
    jobNumber = UCase(InputBox("Enter the Job Number", "Curing Container Routers"))
    
    With Worksheets("F 006 Container Pre-Inspection")
        .Range("A1").Value = jobNumber
        .Range("A4").Formula = "=VLOOKUP(""" & jobNumber & """, 'Database'!A:D, 2, FALSE)"
        .Range("A5").Formula = "=VLOOKUP(""" & jobNumber & """, 'Database'!A:D, 4, FALSE)"
        .Range("M5").Formula = "=VLOOKUP(""" & jobNumber & """, 'Database'!A:D, 3, FALSE)"
    End With
    
    With Worksheets("F 013 Mold Assembly Check List")
        .Range("A1").Value = jobNumber
        .Range("A3").Formula = "=VLOOKUP(""" & jobNumber & """, 'Database'!A:D, 2, FALSE)"
        .Range("A4").Formula = "=VLOOKUP(""" & jobNumber & """, 'Database'!A:D, 4, FALSE)"
        .Range("C4").Formula = "=VLOOKUP(""" & jobNumber & """, 'Database'!A:D, 3, FALSE)"
    End With
    
Call Print_Curing_Empty
    
On Error Resume Next
    
If Err.Number = 0 Then
    MsgBox "Routers Complete", vbInformation + vbOKOnly, SCRIPT_NAME
Else
    MsgBox "Could not find Job Number", vbInformation + vbOKOnly, SCRIPT_NAME
End If
End Sub
```

```
Sub Print_Curing_Empty()
    Worksheets("F 006 Container Pre-Inspection").PrintOut
    Worksheets("F 013 Mold Assembly Check List").PrintOut
End Sub
```

Instead of inputting the jobnumber variable, I would be selecting several jobnumber values that I would want to run.

Comment: Sounds like you would have to loop through a selected range. What did you try which failed?

Comment: ^^^ Use `Application.InputBox` to select a `Range`, which you can then loop through.

Comment: this worked! Thank you! I was trying to over complicate things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the cells are already selected:

```
Dim c As range
If TypeName(Selection) = "Range" Then
    For Each c in Selection.Cells
        jobNumber = c.Value
    
        'Rest of code here

    Next c
Else
    Msgbox "First select one or more JobNumber cells" 
End If
```

Might want to add some code the check that `Selection.Cells.Count` is not some huge number before proceeding with the printing...

Answer (score 0):

Here is basic code to accomplish what you are trying to do. You don't need to use `VLOOPUP`, use an `InputBox` to select all the `DataBase` worksheet `Job Numbers` you want to transfer to the other two worksheets. You can insert a button on your `Database` worksheet and add this code to the button's click event.

```
'Define your worksheet variables
Dim wsData As Worksheet: Set wsData = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Database")
Dim wsCPI As Worksheet: Set wsCPI = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("F 006 Container Pre-Inspection")
Dim wsMACL As Worksheet: Set wsMACL = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("F 013 Mold Assembly Check List")

'Define your non-contiguous range of cells in the Database worksheet, using an InputBox,
'hold down CTRL and select the Job Numbers you want.
Dim jnRng As Range: Set jnRng = Application.InputBox("Select the Job Numbers you want to check (To select non-contiguous ranges, hold down CTRL when moving between ranges)", , , , , , , 8)

    'Loop throgh each cell(rngArea) in the range defined by jnRng
    For Each rngArea In jnRng.Areas
        With wsCPI 'go to the CPI sheet and transfer the values from the Database sheet, then print
            .Range("A1").Value = rngArea.Value
            .Range("A4").Value = rngArea.Offset(, 1).Value
            .Range("A5").Value = rngArea.Offset(, 3).Value
            .Range("M5").Value = rngArea.Offset(, 2).Value
        
            .PrintPreview 'I chose to use ony view the output, change as needed, make sure your pagesetup is correct
        End With
        
        With wsMACL 'go to the MACL sheet and transfer the values from the Database sheet, then print
            .Range("A1").Value = rngArea.Value
            .Range("A3").Value = rngArea.Offset(, 1).Value
            .Range("A4").Value = rngArea.Offset(, 3).Value
            .Range("C4").Value = rngArea.Offset(, 2).Value
        
            .PrintPreview 'same as above
        End With

    Next rngArea 'loop to the next Job Number
```